# Lebsgue measure as a function

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the following two "strange" but interesting questions:

1. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Define a new function $F$ as $F(a)=m(f^{-1}(0,a))$, where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Is $F$ continuous?
2. Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be jointly continuous. Define a new function $F$ as $F(b)=m(\{a\in[0,1] :f(a,b)\le 1 \})$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Is $F$ continuous?

It seems to me that both answers are positive. But I can't give a proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Remark: 1 is false.

Comment: For 1., what if $f$ were strictly increasing, except on an interval over which it was constant?

Comment: That is a nice counter example! So 1 is false. However,I still think 2 is true.